# "True" meaning of "por cierto"

Tags: definiciones, false-friend

I have always thought of the expression of "por cierto" as meaning "certainly" or "surely." It certainly "looks" that way (for certainly). And even Google Translate gives it that meaning, as well as "by the by" (which is similar to "by the way").

Yet when I used this as an answer on another question (since deleted), a native speaker said that it is NEVER used as "surely" or "certainly" in Spain. And the answer was down voted.

I'm confused. What's going on? Is "Por cierto" somehow a "false friend" word? Or is this an acceptable translation in Mexico and/or some South American countries, even though this might not be the case in Spain?

I am an American who has learned "New World" Spanish.

Comment: Great question.

Comment: @CesarGon: Suppose I "undelete" my answer to the other question, and edit it to indicate that "por cierto" is used this way only OUTSIDE of Spain. Will you remove your downvote? (Or did you not downvote it in the first place?"

Comment: Yes, it was me who downvoted your answer ;-) To be honest, I am not certain that "por cierto" is used as "certainly" anywhere *at all*, despite what the DRAE says. Definitely it's not used like that in Spain, and I'm looking forward to seeing answers to your question here that may clarify whether it is used like that anywhere. I'd be happy to remove my downvote if somehow we could make it clear that "por cierto" is far from being accepted as a fair translation for "certainly", to say the least. Maybe a pointer to this question would help. What do you think?

Comment: @CesarGon: My plan was to establish where (if anywhere) it was acceptable. Then point out that it was acceptable only in those places, and NOT Spain.

Comment: @CesarGon: I've also asked about this question on meta: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/213/is-a-definition-translation-acceptable-if-it-is-technically-correct-but-not

Comment: Fair enough. @Miguel 's answer in meta makes sense IMHO.

Comment: Tom, if you're still listening -- I wish I could see what you originally wrote that sparked this question.  Still, I have a pretty good guess what happened.  I suspect that when you wrote "por cierto," you probably meant "cierto" followed by a comma, or "cierto es que."

Comment: It means the Spanish speaker did not understand the English and was not a translator. There is no other explanation. por cierto means of course and indeed and in spoken language, it means by the way. **Just go look in the hard copy of the Spanish>English Larousse**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see [at the RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltObtenerHtml?LEMA=cierto&SUPIND=0&CAREXT=10000&NEDIC=No#por_cierto), "por cierto" has both meanings of "certainly" and "by the way".

I didn't know this until I had a look at it. Here in Spain we only use it as "by the way". So it seems that it also has the meaning of "certainly" in other Spanish speaking countries in America, but not in Spain.

Comment: I am not sure that "por cierto" is used as "certainly" anywhere at all, including America. Can anyone from Spanish-speaking American countries confirm or rebut this?

Comment: Yes, it would be great that someone could confirm my answer.

Comment: At least in El Salvador, "by the way" is most accurate. "Certainly" will fit to "ciertamente", which, if I remember well, it's an adverb.

Comment: `by the way` is how I use `por cierto`

Comment: In Spain it has also the "certainly" meaning in contructions like "dar por cierto", "tomar por cierto", but not when it is alone.

Comment: The RAE does not provide translations of words into English. And, as per the Spanish press,for example, it is not only "by the way". By the way is in spoken Spanish, not written Spanish. You can find it in Spanish writing.

Comment: In view of the lack of response to the first comment, probably it'd be smarter to ask whether there's a country at all where `por cierto` means `certainly`. It sounds very odd to my ears in other meaning than `by the way'.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say for sure this is a fact in each and every Spanish speaking country, but I am pretty sure that the most common use of "por cierto" is "by the way".

The link that JoulSauron added from the Royal Academy of the Spanish Language will certainly include each and every correct use of a word or phrase, but in a lot of cases a lot of those uses and even a lot of the words are not used any more nowadays. It does not mean it is incorrect, only that is not common anymore.

I find that there will be quite a few "unfair downvotes" in this site since most of us Spanish speaking people do not know each and every word, present or past, nor each and every use of each of the words we commonly use.

This I find kind of sad, since Spanish is such a rich language, but is a fact of most languages in the world.

Answer (score 2):

"Por cierto" normally means "by the way" but it's not always true, like in "cuando algo es tomado por cierto..." or "por cierto objeto", if "por cierto" is used just "por cierto" and "por cierto," means "by the way"

Answer (score 1):

"Por cierto" is not always "by the way", and it is wrong to down vote any answer that involves a word/s that are not used in Spain.

The term "false friend word" is only used when two words or phrases in two languages or dialects (or letters in two alphabets) look or sound similar, but differ in meaning.

for sure, by the way, certainly and surely will be correct translations of "Por cierto" depending on the place (geographically differences in the use of) and on the phrase/context.

From sports these days you can see for example on F1 drivers (from non English speaking countries) using "for sure"

```
Q: Do you have all in place to win the race today?
A: For sure, the team and the car are in optimal conditions today.
A: Por cierto, el equipo y el auto estan en optimas condiciones hoy.
```

But note that the same could easyly translated to other forms of affirmations like "De seguro", "por supuesto", "Claro / claro que si"

Commonly used in politics speeches the use of "De por cierto, | delo de por cierto"

```
Q: If you win the elections, will you get us all of this hole ?
A: For sure, I will put this country on the right path.
A: Delo de por cierto, Yo pondre ente pais en el camino correcto.
```

**Expressions and common uses these days**

```
 Por cierto, antes de que me olvide => By the way, before I forget
More commonly: (ah, oh) Antes de que me olvide


 De por cierto que vamos a ganar => Take for sure that we will win.
More commonly: Seguro que vamos a ganar


 Por cierto que voy => For sure I go
More commonly: Claro que voy


 Por cierto que parezca no the creo => Fore true that it looks I don't
   believe you
Remain the same


 Voy por cierto camino => I go true some way/path
Remain the same


 Por camino cierto => true the right path
Remain the same
```

- cierto = true
- por = for
- for true = wrong but the close thing is for sure

You can consider "por cierto" as an expression or phrase that had been replaced by other words and no longer is widely used, despite that, in some places still used in its original form and meaning. It is a word that you can easily avoid and or replace with quite a few others. For sure, if your are not sure about it's true meaning, surely you can avoid it, certainly you will find other words :)

Comment: The translations provided for the dialogue examples are incorrect and don't support the conclusion in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Spain/not Spain question. **It is a question about written versus spoken Spanish.**

**Por cierto**, from the ***Spanish>English hard copy Larousse*** under **locuciones**:

> 1) **of course or indeed**
>
> 2) spoken form: **by the way.** It is followed by three periods, meaning speech.

Three examples of meaning (1) from the Spanish press:

1. **Meaning (1)** Entre todas ellas pagan una auténtica miseria comparado con lo que pagan en el Reino Unido. **Y, por cierto,** la prensa liberal británica reclama a las autoridades fiscales que acaben con este abuso de poder (lo de España tiene otro nombre que abuso).

   Translation: **And, indeed,** the liberal British press is demanding the tax authorities do away this abuse of  power.

   [El Día de Córdoba](https://www.eldiadecordoba.es/opinion/articulos/Alguien-ens-roba_0_995600914.html)
2. **Meaning (1)** En todo caso, un programa de reformas al que **por cierto** la prensa ha dado escasísima cobertura y que recuerda mucho a las 100 medidas que presentó en su día Miguel Sebastián.

   Translation: In any event, a reform program that, **of course,** the press has scarcely covered and which is very reminiscent of the 100 measures that Miguel Sebastián presented in his time.

   [Europa Press](https://www.europapress.es/otr-press/firmas/carmentomas/noticia-carmen-tomas-agenda-cambio-20190210080134.html)
3. **Meaning (1)**  — **Por cierto**, la abuela compra todos los años el mismo número. Dice que algún día tocará. ¿Si haces eso se elevan tus posibilidades de ganar?

   Translation: **Of course**, your grandmother buys the same number every year. She said that one day, she'll win. If you do this, do your chances of winning improve?

   Please note: although the sentence above could be begun with *by the way*, that doesn't work so well here.

   [NIUS website](https://www.niusdiario.es/loteria-de-navidad/mas-probable-ganar-loteria-nino-navidad_18_2869920138.html)

[Note: please do not edit, I have it like I want it. Thanks.]

Comment: You made a good point, +1. // I would favor "as a matter of fact" for the last two examples, but I suppose it's a subtle difference. // An easy formatting improvement would be to put the greater than symbol in front of the examples.  And you could italicize the translations.  I've respected your request not to edit your post -- but note that by the rules of Stack Exchange, one is supposed to be willing to allow others to edit one's posts collaboratively (but of course one can roll back an edit partially or completely).

Comment: @aparente001 Sure, edit away then. I personally like it like it is. I have the word translation, I don't need the greater symbol. The answer chosen is not very complete and no one made the distinction: written/spoken. They got caught up in: in Spain and outside Spain. Of course is used in English writing.

Comment: Okay, I tried to be gentle.  But if you don't like it, you can roll the whole thing back.

Comment: @aparente001 It's fine. You didn't wreck it.

Comment: Fine praise, I guess....

Comment: @aparente001 This is again one of those cases where all the answers are half-baked. Not to  toot my own horn or anything, but for others not to acknowledge my basic point plus the uses I found in written Spanish is really too much. And then to choose an answer based on the RAE through one's own translation into English is odd. Finally, I quoted a bilingual authoritative source. That doesn't seem to matter either. Conclusion? Cluelessness works better than enterado-ness. [joke] Happy New Year to you.:)

Comment: Lambie, I don't think you have enough rep here yet to see the actual votes.  I personally upvoted your answer.  Someone else downvoted, but without leaving any feedback, which I find frustrating.  Let's hope to get some feedback as people trickle back from vacation.

Comment: @aparente001 This is what I see: spanish.stackexchange.com/users/19182/lambie I can see a + 8 on the right and a zero on the left. I wish somewhere on this site (SE in general) they explained points. I don't understand them.  My main point is that my answer is more thorough and even shows links.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot, you can deduce votes from the rep changes (click on the trophy, top right).  An upvote produces a rep change of +10, and a downvote produces a change of -2.  // Here's the index for the FAQ on the big Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/287826.  But watch out.  If you think voting is sometimes harsh here -- the big Meta can be much harsher.  If you have questions it would probably be better to ask them at our local Meta: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/ or at La Tertulia (chat).

Comment: @aparente001 Thank you for that. I can't possibly work my way through all that "literature". Why the heck don't they just have a heading with points in the title? All the meta stuff (both the meta sites and the meta texts) are too much and too overwhelming. I try and avoid them.  I am aware of chat rooms, thanks. I think those who have digested all the meta stuff are computer geeks. Normal people would find it too much.

Comment: I agree, it is overwhelming.  I am farther along in you in understanding some of the mechanics of the site, but I have only scratched the surface.

Comment: @aparente001I care about language usage and translation, the rest just makes my eyes glaze over, really. Gotta do some work now. I've been avoiding it.